# Mean of $t$ in the logistic regression model

Tags: logistic, classification, expected-value, sigmoid-curve, activation-function

The question comes from a sentence of page 208 of Christopher M. Bishop's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning". The sentence is excerpted as follows:

[image]

My questions are mainly two:

1. Why $\mathbb E[t]=\sigma({\bf x})$?

As explained in section 1.5 on page 38, the training samples for classification are drawn from joint distribution $p({\bf x},t)$. So I think the $t$ here is the $t$ in $p({\bf x},t)$ on page 38, the random variable representing target value. This $t$ conforms to Bernoulli distribution, so its expectation is known to be the probability of $t=1$ (Eq (2.3) on page 69), which I think should be unconditional probability $p(\mathcal C_1)$. On the other hand, I am guessing $\sigma({\bf x})$ denotes "the activation function with input vector ${\bf x}$" as mentioned under Eq (4.117) on page 212. That is, $p(\mathcal C_1|{\bf\phi})$, according to Eq (4.87) on page 205, which is a conditional probability. In general, unconditional probability $p(\mathcal C_1)$ is not equal to conditional probability $p(\mathcal C_1|{\bf\phi})$. So, why can we write $\mathbb E[t]=\sigma({\bf x})$? This is the first thing that confuses me.

2. Still for equation $\mathbb E[t]=\sigma({\bf x})$.

$\mathbb E[t]$, as an expectation, is a deterministic constant. The right side, $\sigma({\bf x})$, however, is a function of random variable $\bf x$ in $p({\bf x},t)$ on page 38, so it should be a random variable too. So, how can we equate a random variable with a deterministic number?

Thank you for your help with my questions.

Comment: I think this is shorthand notation for $E[t|x]$, the conditionality probably assumed implicitly as the distribution of $x$ doesn't need to be specified in regression.

Comment: @jwimberley: I agree. That makes a lot more sense.